# Add Url to database Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a rails app using the vimeo gem. I want to add the thumbnail address for each video created and add the link to the database so I can image_tag the url on my index view, but I am not sure how to save the url to my database upon creation of each video file.

I can access the  'thumbnail_small' on my show page easily enough, but cannot call it on my index so I figure that it would be best to save the url to my database.

Index view

```
<h1>Videos</h1>
<hr>
<% @videos.each do |videos| %>
<%= link_to (image_tag videos.thumb), video_path(videos) %>
<% end %>
```

Video Controller

```
def index
 @videos = Video.all
  end

def show
 @video = Video.find(params[:id])
 @vimeo = Vimeo::Simple::Video.info(@video.vimeo_clip_id)[0]['id']
 end

def new
 @video = Video.new :thumb => @thumb
 @thumb = Vimeo::Simple::Video.info(@vimeo.vimeo_clip_id)[0]['thumbnail_small']
end
```

Schema

```
  create_table "video", :force => true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",    :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    :null => false
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "vimeo_clip_id"
    t.string   "thumb"
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. I used an update_attribute call to update the database once the post was created.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood but it seems you are simply saving the URL as a string.
    t.string  "url"

Comment: I'm hoping to save the url as a string to thumb.